# Flutter Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted

Tags: flutter

I have gone through the usual answers.  I have edited the info.plist on iOS and added the network_config.xml in Android.  This works perfectly when running the project from XCode, but when trying to run the debug from Android Studio, I get the

```
Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.54 not permitted
```

Seems like Flutter is ignoring my iOS and Android configurations regarding this matter, but only when running it directly from Android Studio.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please add below code in your manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest ...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

You can read details here https://medium.com/@imstudio/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted-73c1c9e3b803

Comment: I have also tried this.  As  I mentioned on my question, this works when running directly from the compiled project, but not when debugging from Android Studio.

Comment: I added this android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" and working perfectly in my project.

Comment: Dude, you are right.  I had the usesClearTextTraffic line on the wrong xml key inside de Manifiest!

Comment: Its not working on my project why?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in your manifest file both

**main-AndroidManifest**

```
 <application
        android:label="vvp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

**debug-AndroidManifest**

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
```