# Flutter my app stuck at white screen after downloading from play store in some devices

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-app-bundle

I released an app for android. I wanted to make some updates and after update, it started to freeze in starting as white screen. When I debug, it works perfectly in the same device which freezes after downloading from store. In emulator, I download the app from store and it works. What can be the problem causing that?

I use command `flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=somepath`

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  provider: ^5.0.0
  toast: ^0.1.5
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.2
  fl_chart: ^0.20.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  device_info: ^2.0.0
  synchronized: ^3.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_performance: ^0.6.0+2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  workmanager: ^0.4.0
  get_it: ^7.1.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+3


  

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  generate: true
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I tried to make my gradle version 3.5.1
I also tried to delete the packages I added but it still freezes when downloading from store.

Edit: I see that error in logcat when app is starting:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Exception encountered, read, javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher$EVP_CIPHER.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:602)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:365)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
        at c.b.a.b.b.b(Unknown Source:32)
        at c.b.a.a.b(Unknown Source:11)
        at c.b.a.a.d(Unknown Source:7)
        at c.b.a.a.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at c.b.a.a$b.run(Unknown Source:134)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    , null)
```

Edit 2: As I look-up, this may cause because of `flutter_secure_storage` package. I am doing a `.read` in my main and many people faced this issue as I see. What I do now is, I will try to change `flutter_secure_storage` version as long as I find the working version.

Comment: are you sure you're not not initializing any of the flutter_secure_storage's keys as empty strings?

Comment: @GuilhermeV. I am pretty sure but I will double-check that. Also, if that is the case, same code, same build giving error with some devices and works perfectly with some others. Wouldn't be the case error for every device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow HTTP traffic\network access permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

[Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623444/13558035)

Comment: I have these permissions but android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" is only in my debug manifest. I will add it also to manifest inside main but if this is the problem, isn't the app freeze for all devices?

Comment: Add it to main, and run your app in release mode, and validate. `flutter run --release`

Comment: It worked with flutter run --release, now I will put it in alpha test and try...

Comment: Looks like that does not work, I am still getting stuck when I download it from store. Device's andorid version is 10, api level 29, as it said, can this be because of that?

Comment: Connect it to `adb logcat` and see what is being printed in the log.

Comment: Can I do it in VSCode?

Comment: From terminal, any terminal.

Comment: I edited the post, added the error on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this error is the device's android API version.

steps to solve this issue:

- Upgrade both `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to the latest version(be the answer posted 30 is the last version).
- Run the app in release mode using the devices that show the error by terminal

> flutter run --release

.

- May use firebase [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics)! to track issues/errors like this.

Comment: Both my compile version and targetsdk version are 30 and my minsdk is 22, trying on release.

Comment: Good, please provide the release run log after running on the real device that shows the error.